# Wait for HttpPostedBaseFile SaveAs to complete

Tags: c#, file-upload, upload, save, save-as

I want to wait for SaveAs to complete before continuing, I've tried a few different solutions but it still just continues immediately, not waiting for the upload to complete. What I've tried:

Creating a wrapping function to return an int (this is what I found on Stack Overflow):

```
    public int SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string filePath)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            try
            {
                file.SaveAs(filePath);

                return 1;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And running this in my main method:

```
var success = SaveFile(hpf, savedFileName);
```

I also tried checking to see if the file is ready:

```
while (!IsFileReady(filePath))
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Calling this:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "L,I")]
    public static bool IsFileReady(String sFilename)
    {
        // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
        // is no longer locked by another process.
        try
        {
            using (FileStream inputStream = System.IO.File.Open(sFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                if (inputStream.Length > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Again, no luck. I just need to make sure file.SaveAs(...) waits until the file completes uploading to continue.

Comment: I am not sure of the code but I think that Task/await might be what you are looking for.

Comment: You swallow the exceptions. Check if there are any...

Comment: There are no exceptions.